# Parsing a nested json array

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I need to parse the following nested json.

```
{  
   "status":1,
   "value":{  
      "details":[  
         {  
            "text":"this is test",
            "company":"General Marketing Company",
            "date":"05-DEC-15"
         },
         {  
            "text":"this is test2",
            "company":"NJ, Chennai",
            "date":"05-DEC-15"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Sample test message for welcome",
            "company":"sd",
            "date":"22-JAN-16"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Following is my code,

```
NSString* testimonialResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [testimonialResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSLog(@"Response %@",jsonDic[@"value"][@"details"]);
```

The above code can actually be able to parse the contents within details in general but it cant be able to parse each of those datas uniquely.say for instance, my code doesn't list all company names,texts,dates uniquely.

Comment: try this if work then tell me so i can put it in answer     self.Array=[jsonDic valueForKey:@"compnay"];
 NSLog(@"Array : %@",self.Array);

Comment: What do you mean with "it can't be able to parse each of those datas"?. Your code parses the file correctly, the dates are strings so you shouldn't have any problem parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

```
NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
NSArray *dataArray = jsonDic[@"value"][@"details"];

 for (NSDictionary *tmp in dataArray)
{
 NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"text"] forKey:@"text"];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"company"] forKey:@"company"];
[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"date"] forKey:@"date"];

  [yourArrayName addObject:temp];

}
```

**EDit**

if you want to stop here , use this

```
NSArray * finalAray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: jsonDic[@"value"][@"details"]]
```

Comment: Why you should create another dictionary if each object in the array details is already a dictionary?

Comment: if he need use it else no need, in my assumption, if he modify it is easy

Answer (score 1):

```
**You can use this**

 NSArray *array_details = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"value"] objectForKey:@"details"];
 NSArray Compay_arr = [array_details valueForKey: @"company"];
 NSArray text_arr = [array_details valueForKey: @"text"];
 NSArray date_arr = [array_details valueForKey: @"date"];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
NSString* testimonialResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [testimonialResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithArray: jsonDic[@"value"][@"details"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray: jsonDic[@"value"][@"details"]];
NSArray *companyNames = [array valueForKey:@"company"];
```

`companyNames` contains all company names